# Editor in Markdown Preview project not working after I downloaded 'Marked'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-marked

Trying to make a Markdown Previewer for a freeCodeCamp project. My editor was working fine, but now I can't update the markdown in my state; it's stuck on the placeholder text I wrote. Whenever I try to type in the editor textarea, it sends my cursor to the bottom of the text box. Editor is supposed to just accept an event using a handleChange method, and I cannot figure out why it's not working for the life of me. Worked fine until I downloaded Marked. Here's a [link to the CodePen](https://codepen.io/Hare-Bear/pen/eYVOmRP%27) where I'm fiddling with it. The onChange function is pretty standard.`handleChange(event) {this.setState({markdown: event.target.value})};`

Answer (score 0):

Update: found out the problem. Figured out I needed to set the markdown as the defaultValue prop, not the value prop.